# nginx+php-fpm Permission denied

Tags: php, nginx, centos, php-fpm

в www.conf

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

и
    user nginx;
    group nginx;

лог

```
2018/09/10 20:24:55 [crit] 2443#2443: *14 connect() to unix:/var/run/php- 
fpm/php-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 192.168.1.111, server: 192.168.1.200, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: 
"192.168.1.200"
2018/09/10 20:24:55 [error] 2443#2443: *14 open() 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), 
 client: 192.168.1.111, server: 192.168.1.200, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
 upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.1.200"
```

вывод $ namei -l /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

```
 f: /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
 dr-xr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root var
 lrwxrwxrwx root root run -> ../run
 dr-xr-xr-x root root   ..
 drwxr-xr-x root root   run
 drwxr-xr-x root root php-fpm
 srw-rw---- root root php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: что ж вы не приложили (нажав [edit]) вывод `$ namei -l /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`?

Comment: ну вот видите: сокет (а значит и процесс, его создающий — *php-fpm*) принадлежит пользователю `root`.

Comment: А изменить как? Я просто совсем ещё новичок

Comment: в конфигурационном файле программы *php-fpm*

Comment: А что на что менять?
У меня :
user nginx;
group nginx